# Selenium get text returning NULL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I'm adding some data through my automation script and once it is added, I need to verify it on screen.

However when I'm using below code to verify the text present on screen - get text method always returns `NULL`.

Here is the code which I'm using

```
String expectedOC = "9999";
String actualOC = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='104429O']/div/div[1]/div[2]")).getText();   

Assert.assertTrue(actualOC.contains(expectedOC));
```

Comment: Share HTML code sample for the same

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)